# How to build a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I have a really really big question which is how to write a social networking website like facebook? I want to know which language should I use and why. And also the relationship of them or the whole structure of website. Only a general idea of blue print will be all right. However I don't mind if u can tell me things in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's good to know that you "don't mind" if someone here can define for you in detail how to build Facebook.  However, nobody here is going to do that.  If you have a *specific* question about code you're writing, we can help with that.  But what you're looking for right now are introductory tutorials on website development.  Choose a language and/or framework and search for tutorials on Google.

Comment: Facebook and other social media websites use all web languages, HTML Css JavaScript php and more. Your question is way too broad, and don't expect us to build a website for you

Comment: Okay. The problem is I don't know where to start   Sad.

Comment: Is like asking a mechanic how to build a ferrari bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: You can't realistically without a huge team of experts and lots of money. If you're a full-stack developer I'm sure you can pull off a website that has user profiles and a commenting system just with HTML, CSS, javascript, AJAX, and something like PHP/MySQL on the backend (lots of options here). Facebook is obviously a lot more complicated than that though, especially with all the asynchronous features going on such as the chat system.

Extended answer: https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2013/05/20/how-is-a-facebook-like-site-actually-created-from-scratch/#71ee985bdd2d

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot